# linux ksh how to remove all directories except the latest some directories

Tags: linux, shell, ksh

I am using Linux ksh to remove some old directories that I don't want.

What I use is this:

```
   #! /bin/ksh
   OLD=/opt/backup
   DIR_PREFIX="active"
   DIRS=$(ls ${OLD} -t | grep ${DIR_PREFIX})
   i=0
   while [[ $i -lt ${#DIRS[*]} ]]; do
       if [ $i -gt 4 ];
      then
          echo ${DIRS[$i]}
          ((i++))
      else
          ((i++))
      fi
  done
```

what I am trying to do is: to store a list all the directories sorted by time into a variable-I assume it would be an array but somehow the size of it is 1... ..., then in the while loop, if the position of the directory is greater than 4, then I print out the directory name.

Any idea of how to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
OLD=/opt/backup
DIR_PREFIX="active"
DIRS_RESULT=$(ls ${OLD} -t | grep ${DIR_PREFIX})
i=0
for DIR in ${DIRS_RESULT}
    do
        if [ $i -gt 4 ];
        then
            echo ${DIR}
            rm -rf ${DIR}
            ((i++))
        else
            ((i++))
        fi
    done
```

this one works for me

Answer (score 1):

If all you want is to print all but the first four entries, just pipe it to `head` or `sed`:

```
#!/bin/sh
OLD=/opt/backup
DIR_PREFIX=active
ls $OLD -t | grep $DIR_PREFIX | sed 1,4d | while read DIR; do
    echo $DIR;
done
```

If you are just using `echo`, the while loop is redundant, but presumably you will have more commands in the loop.